# how to avoid mass liking and disliking in voting system

Tags: php

i know this question has been asked before but i have never found an appropriate answer.

i want to build a blog-like page with different entrys, each of them can be liked and disliked.

i read that i could create a database with previous likes, the ip adress and the user clients and set cookies as well. but user clients can be manipulated, ip addresses can be changes and cookies can be deleted.

how do i avoid mass disliking or liking if the attacking person deletes cookies and changes ip on every like/dislike?

Comment: you can buy facebook likes, nothing will ever stop determined people. Its a trade of in the amount of time you spend trying to stop them vs the befit for doing so

Comment: Please be sure to read the helpful descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking how you can absolutely 100% guarantee that no one can vote twice, I think the answer to that is, It can't be done. Not in practice; maybe not even in theory.

As you say, you could drop a cookie on the user's computer -- but a sophisticated enough user could delete the cookie. You could keep track of each voter's IP -- but someone could vote from different computers, or submit votes through proxies. You could require a user to create an account and only let each account vote once -- but someone could create multiple accounts. You could require users to supply a social security number or drivers license number -- but a someone could use a fake or stolen number.

You could charge people a fee to vote. This wouldn't stop someone from voting twice but the number of times he could vote would be limited by his bank account and how much he's willing to spend.

I suppose theoretically you could require the user to submit his fingerprints or a DNA sample. But to the best of my knowledge very few people have fingerprint readers attached to their computers and even fewer have DNA analyzers, so I don't think this is particularly practical. And even if they did, how would you insure that someone didn't go out and collect DNA samples from random strangers -- say, collecting discarded paper cups at the local fast food place -- to run through the DNA scanner?

You could do any of the above, and no doubt many other things, to make it HARDER for someone to vote twice. But if people care enough to want to break your system, you end up with a game where you put up fences and they find ways to climb over them or cut holes in them.

This does bring up an amusing point. There are ways to verify that someone claiming to be person X is the same person X who came by yesterday: For example we can ask him to supply a password on the first visit and then repeat that password on subsequent visits. An impostor would have difficultly finding out the password. But how do you prove that you are a DIFFERENT person? It hardly works to say that he must prove that he does NOT know the password. What would stop a person from deliberately giving the wrong password?

Answer (score 1):

Require users to log in before they can cast votes. Just like Stack Overflow does.

[image]

Comment: i can still create 500 accounts, but it takes a while :-)